# Resize the scale on the dual y-axis and on an area chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, area-chart

I want to scale the geom_line chart so that the area chart looks like this image (example).
In my example I was able to scale both Y-axes but geom_line does not obey the second Y-axis.
[image]

This is my code

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- read.csv("route/file.csv")
gas <- as.data.frame(df[, 1:3])

ggplot(gas) +
  geom_area(aes(x = año, y = qg, fill = " Qg [MMMpc]"),
            colour = "#ffed63", alpha = 0.9) +
  geom_line(aes(x = año, y = np, colour = "Gp [MMMpc]"),
            linewidth=1, linetype = "dashed")+
  scale_colour_manual(values = "#C5B21D")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = "#ffed63")+
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "black"))) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = gas$año) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 60, 10),
                     limits = c(0, 180),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ .*3,
                                         breaks = seq(0, 180, 30),
                                         labels = seq(0, 180, 30),
                                         name = "Total acumulado [MMMpc]")))
```

and the data is

```
    año    qg     np
1  2019  0.33   0.12
2  2020 13.05   4.90
3  2021 14.88  10.33
4  2022 13.67  15.32
5  2023 12.59  19.91
6  2024 12.23  24.39
7  2025 11.33  28.52
8  2026 16.32  34.48
9  2027 49.21  52.44
10 2028 48.21  70.09
11 2029 47.06  87.27
12 2030 42.40 102.74
13 2031 31.85 114.37
14 2032 24.56 123.36
15 2033 19.61 130.51
16 2034 16.06 136.38
17 2035 13.42 141.28
18 2036 11.43 145.46
19 2037  9.80 149.04
20 2038  8.49 152.13
21 2039  7.35 154.82
22 2040  5.97 157.00
23 2041  4.21 158.54
24 2042  3.70 159.89
```

Comment: secondary axes in ggplot2 are just decorations -- everything is mapped based on the primary axis and nothing will "obey" the 2nd axis. You probably need  `geom_line(aes(x = año, y = np/3 ...`